# MongoDB - Select multiple sub-dicuments from array using $elemMatch

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection like the following:-

```
{
  _id: 5,
  "org_name": "abc",
  "items": [
    {
      "item_id": "10",
      "data": [
        // Values goes here
      ]
    },
    {
      "item_id": "11",
      "data": [
        // Values goes here
      ]
    }
  ]
},

// Another sub document
{
  _id: 6,
  "org_name": "sony",
  "items": [
    {
      "item_id": "10",
      "data": [
        // Values goes here
      ]
    },
    {
      "item_id": "11",
      "data": [
        // Values goes here
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Each sub document corresponds to individual organizations and each organization has an `array` of `items` in them.

What I need is to get the select individual elements from the `items` array, by providing `item_id`.

I already tried this:-

```
db.organizations.find({"_id": 5}, {items: {$elemMatch: {"item_id": {$in: ["10", "11"]}}}})
```

But it is returning either the item list with *item_id* "10" `OR` the item list with *item_id* "11".

**What I need is** is the get values for both item_id 10 and 11 for the organization "abc". Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**update2**:

```
db.organizations.aggregate([
    // you can remove this to return all your data
    {$match:{_id:5}},
    // unwind array of items
    {$unwind:"$items"},
    // filter out all items not in 10, 11
    {$match:{"items.item_id":{"$in":["10", "11"]}}},
    // aggregate again into array
    {$group:{_id:"$_id", "items":{$push:"$items"}}}
])
```

**update**:

```
db.organizations.find({
    "_id": 5,
    items: {$elemMatch: {"item_id": {$in: ["10", "11"]}}}
})
```

**old** Looks like you need [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/), particularly [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) operator:

```
db.organizations.aggregate([
    {$match:{_id:5}}, // you can remove this to return all your data
    {$unwind:"$items"}
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Roman. But what I need is not to select *all* the `items`. Sorry if I was not clear, but what I need is to specify the `item_id`s of the items which I need the data from.

Comment: @Sparky ok, see updated, we'll see if I understood you now :). You have to specify `items` in the first parameter of `find`.

Comment: I think you understand what I need now, but the updated query is also giving me all the items in the given organization (_id: 5) :(

Comment: @Sparky ok, 3rd attempt, if you want to filter out some elements from array, I think you still need aggregation framework :), see updated

Comment: Thanks @Roman, its working :) :) Thanks a lot. 1 more lil doubt too. Currently the output has `item_id` only. What if I need to get a bunch of other properties also about the returned items, say `item_id` and `item_name`? Can u please please update ur answer?? :)

Comment: Thanks. You saved my few years :)